# Web.Config Entries for AzureStorage in AzureWebApp

Tags: azure, azure-storage, ashx

Im trying to use .ashx on AzureWebApp to Access Azure Storage (Table).

My .ashx file header is as below.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="glc_ActivityLogTest" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class temp : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {   ......
```

When I execute the same, the event log has

Process information:

```
Process ID: 5404

Process name: w3wp.exe

Account name: IIS APPPOOL\getme



Exception information:

Exception type: HttpCompileException

Exception message: 

d:\home\site\wwwroot\server\glc_ActivityLogTest.ashx(5): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I do not use Visual Studio, and handle the entire solution as a collection .ashx files with Azure Web App and Azure SQL.

Im sure, Im missing web.config entries, and some dlls probably in my bin directory.

Can you please suggest on what entries are needed.

My Web.Config is as follows :

```
 <configuration>
  <system.web>
  <compilation>
     <assemblies>
     <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
     <add assembly="System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
     </assemblies>
  </compilation>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS,FILE" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated..

I also do not use a Visual Studio or a Windows Machine. I use a Mac for my development and Azure for all my Server needs.

Comment: How do you add references to dlls in your project? Do you simply put them in the bin folder?

Comment: Just drop them in the bin folder.  Other than newtonsoft there are no other dependencies..

Comment: How  do you  deploy your project? What's your development or deployment tools?

Comment: ftp the deliverables into their directories on Azure.. This is a plain and simple REST , .ASHX implementation . I would prefer to know what I am doing, and hence physically manage deployment.

Comment: Hi do you need any other information, please let me know.. Any inputs will be great !!